# Unable to add framework

Tags: objective-c, frameworks, xcode8

I have an application for iOS that uses another custom framework. I have compiled the framework and added it to the project, but the linker keeps complaining of it being missing. To add it to the project, I simply clicked the + button under Linked frameworks and libraries and added the .framework package. Do I have to do anything else? How do I get detailed info about the problem, because the path to the framework is correct for sure as I browsed to it using the file browser.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a pod framework or library.Check under products folder if your framework is present and not in red. ELse try deleting it from Products and adding again .

Comment: There is no red anywhere, and the framework is listed under Frameworks and not under products. AFAIK only products are listed under products.

Comment: Did you check "Copy items into destination group's folder" option when you were adding.

Comment: You can follow below steps:

1) Create sub-folder in your project and add framework into that folder.
2) Now, open Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries. And click on '+' button.
3) Then click on "Add Other" instead of adding default framework.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simple, and so is the solution. The framework can't be found by the linker, which looks only into predefined paths under

> Build Settings -> Search Path -> Framework Search Paths

I had to add the framework folder under this and everything went well.

Most people do not face this problem because they decide to copy the framework to the project while dragging and dropping. I decided to not copy and faced this problem, but there is always a solution. More info can be found at https://fixed-it.blogspot.in/2016/10/xcode-objective-c-custom-frameworks-and.html. Thanks for all the help.